# Emconfigure pkg-config dependencies unresolved / Emscripten

Tags: c++, cross-compiling, emscripten

Tying to compile a project using Emscripten with a CMakeList and pkg-config tool

Problem : dependencies using pkg-config are unresolved

Using :

`cmake .`

Works prefectly.

Using emscripten :

`emconfigure cmake .`

[image]
The dependencies of the project are unresolved for some reasons.

Been investigating and found out Emscripten is using his own pkg-config 
search path to resolved dependencies / using emconfigure :

```
emconfigure pkg-config --list-all
```

Does not list all the libs available through the classic =>

```
pkg-config --list-all
```

I'm probably missing something there.

Is there a way of forcing emscripten to use the global pkg-config system ?

Edit : 
Is it needed to compile dependencies first into Emscripten ?

Comment: I thought emconfigure was for running cmake or ./configure. Won't you have to build eigen under emscripten first?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if I need to build those dependencies into emscripten before-hand

Comment: If you're going to link your emscripten-compiled code to the eigen library you'll want to make sure you have built eigen using the emscripten toolchain and correct options. By default, it'll build a .js (executable). You probably want to coerce it into building a static library (.a extension). 
I have done this with other libraries (boost, openssl(!), protocol buffers, etc) but not eigen.

Comment: Is there any tutorial around you'll recommend to build those library before-hand, or any repo to help ?

Comment: Hum, no I had to figure it all out for myself. On thing you could try is using the github repos ruslo/hunter and ruslo/polly. Polly is a collection of toolchains for cmake and hunter is a dependency manager which takes into account your current toolchain. polly has a toolchain for emscripten.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issue where a library I was using was calling `pkg_check_modules(GSL gsl)`.  I was able to fix issues with e.g. `find_package(DoubleConversion REQUIRED)` by providing cmake args

`-DDoubleConversion_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/home/myuser/code/double-conversion/libdouble-conversion.a -DDoubleConversion_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/home/myuser/code/double-conversion/double-conversion`

to the cmake call but when I tried to do something similar with the GSL libraries, defining GSL_INCLUDE_DIR and GSL_LIBRARY they couldn't be found and I got errors about headers missing in the `make` call.

What I realized from the docs for [PKG_CONFIG_USE_CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html#variable:PKG_CONFIG_USE_CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH) is that (theoretically) if I just use a single arg `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="${LIBS_DIR}/double-conversion;${LIBS_DIR}/gsl"` then I shouldn't have to find the library path and include path for each library and I don't need to care whether the packages were found using find_package or pkg_check_modules. However, it does not seem to be a working replacement for the args I used for DoubleConversion nor does it provide me with a way of telling pkg_check_modules where to look for me GSL library. Perhaps cmake is too opinionated in where it expects include headers and libs.